# Transfer a file through SFTP with a different user using JSch in java

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am currently doing a SFTP file transfer using JSch as follows,

```
public  void send (String fileName) {
    String SFTPHOST = "host:IP";
    int SFTPPORT = 22;
    String SFTPUSER = "username";
    String SFTPPASS = "password";
    String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "file/to/transfer";

    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    System.out.println("preparing the host information for sftp.");
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
        session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Host connected.");
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        System.out.println("sftp channel opened and connected.");
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
        File f = new File(fileName);
        channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
        log.info("File transfered successfully to host.");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println("Exception found while tranfer the response.");
    }
    finally{

        channelSftp.exit();
        System.out.println("sftp Channel exited.");
        channel.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Channel disconnected.");
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Host Session disconnected.");
    }
}
```

I need to do this transfer as a different user i.e I need to trigger pbrun first and then perform the transfer using the new user. I could not find such an option in JSch or ChannelSftp. Is it possible to do the same using the mentioned APIs.

Comment: "I need to trigger pbrun first and then perform the transfer using the new user." Does SFTP even support this?

Comment: Looks like you can do ```channelSftp.chown(uid, f.getName());```

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: chown will work only if you have root access right ??

Comment: In practice, yes. There's a chance chown only works with sftp if you're root or if you can sudo chown.

Comment: Hi Anand, Have you got any workaround for this?